# Coldfusion 2018 not working for other extensions like htm in IIS

Tags: coldfusion, windows-server, iis-10, coldfusion-2018

I am moving my ColdFusion site from CF-11 to CF-2018. I have sites which have ColdFusion code in .htm extension files, which is CF-11. Now I am moving my site to new server which has CF-2018, but .htm extensions are not working under the new server. I have already added the handler mapping under IIS. But it is showing me this error

> 404 - The page you are trying to access can not be displayed. Please try again or notify the administrator.

I have also followed the steps mention here: [IIS manual connector configuration](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/coldfusion-iis-manual-connector-configuration.html)

Any suggestions on exactly what I am missing?

**Update from comments**

Both .htm and .html mappings are added, including mime type, all the available settings for both extensions are added in IIS. There is no information is appearing under the ColdFusion Logs

Comment: make sure you enabled the static content feature of the iis. [image](https://imgur.com/qPZR3pg) and check for the mime type is available or not.

Comment: Yes I have make sure that it is already enabled. any other suggestion?

Comment: is .html mime type is available in the iis? check iis and Coldfusion log for more detail.

Comment: both .htm and .html mapping is added, including mime type, all the available settings form both extensions are added in IIS. There is no information is appearing under the Coldfusion Logs.

Comment: please check the iis log and get what is the sub status code. and please share the full error snapshot.

Answer (score 0):

@Shehzad Malik, The steps are indeed different from CF11-forward, You need to edit the **uriworkermap.properties** file for your web connector(s).

For your more info you can refer the below link, That they clearly said about it.

https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2267506

http://www.carehart.org/blog/client/index.cfm/2011/10/14/coldfusion_processing_html_or_other_file_extensions

I hope it's helpful to you. Thanks.